# java.lang.IllegalStateException on Android 9

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, illegalstateexception, android-9.0-pie

Recently I have updated my API target to 28. I have to do couple of changes. I am getting crash dump error from huge no of users(8,396) with IllegalStateException exception.

- play console crashes

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3584)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:235)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1779)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6981)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1666)
>   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1611)
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:677)
>   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:677)
>   at ch.corten.aha.worldclock.WorldClockWidgetProvider.onClockTick (WorldClockWidgetProvider.java:147)
>   at ch.corten.aha.worldclock.ClockWidgetProvider.onReceive (ClockWidgetProvider.java:115)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3575)
> ```

- **WorldClockWidgetProvider.java:147** reporting at *context.startService(service);*. from below Function snapshot.

> ```
>   @Override
>     protected void onClockTick(Context context) {
>         Intent service = new Intent(context, WorldClockWidgetService.class);
>         context.startService(service);
>     }
> ```

- **ClockWidgetProvider.java:115** which means at "*onClockTick(context);*" from below Function snapshot.

> ```
> @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         Log.e(TAG, "Onrecive called Biswajit");
>         super.onReceive(context, intent);
>         if (WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())
>                 || CLOCK_TICK_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
>             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>             if (pm.isScreenOn()) {
>                 onClockTick(context);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

All the reported devices are Android 9 and API 29.

- Build.gradile snippet

> ```
> dependencies {
>
>     //compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
>     //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
>     implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.7'
>     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
>     implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
>     //noinspection GradleCompatible
>     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
>     implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.2'
>
>     }
> ```

- called service

> ```
> import android.content.Intent;
>
> public class WorldClockWidgetService extends IntentService {
>
>     public WorldClockWidgetService() {
>         super("WorldClockWidgetService");
>     }
> ```

***Proposed Solution?:***

- Context of **Intent** service

> ```
> public class WorldClockWidgetService extends IntentService {
>
>     public WorldClockWidgetService() {
>         super("WorldClockWidgetService");
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
>         WorldClockWidgetProvider.updateTime(this);
>     }
> }
> ```

Which will be **replaced** by

> ```
> public class WorldClockWidgetService extends JobIntentService {
>
>     public WorldClockWidgetService() {
>         super("WorldClockWidgetService");
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
>         WorldClockWidgetProvider.updateTime(this);
>     }
> }
> ```

**Error: Getting error**

[image: Error]

**content of WorldClockWidgetProvider**

```
public class WorldClockWidgetProvider extends ClockWidgetProvider {
private static final boolean SANS_JELLY_BEAN_MR1 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1;

static {
    registerClockWidget(WorldClockWidgetProvider.class);
}

@Override
protected void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    updateAppWidgetStatic(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
}

private static void updateAppWidgetStatic(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    // Create an Intent to launch WorldClockActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WorldClockActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
    // to the button
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.world_clock_widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_widget, pendingIntent);

    // update view
    updateViews(context, views);

    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
    Clocks.TIMEZONE_ID,
    Clocks.CITY
};

private static final int[] CITY_IDS = {
    R.id.city_text1,
    R.id.city_text2,
    R.id.city_text3,
    R.id.city_text4,
};

private static final int[] TIME_IDS = {
    R.id.time_text1,
    R.id.time_text2,
    R.id.time_text3,
    R.id.time_text4,
};

private static void updateViews(Context context, RemoteViews views) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean autoSort = prefs.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.auto_sort_clocks_key), true);
    Cursor cursor = Clocks.widgetList(context, PROJECTION, autoSort);

    try {
        int n = 0;
        DateFormat df = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
        long now = DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis();
        final int maxEntries = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.worldclock_widget_max_entries);
        while (cursor.moveToNext() && n < CITY_IDS.length
                && n < maxEntries) {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Clocks.TIMEZONE_ID));
            String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Clocks.CITY));
            views.setTextViewText(CITY_IDS[n], city);
            DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID(id);
            if (SANS_JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                views.setTextViewText(TIME_IDS[n], TimeZoneInfo.formatDate(df, tz, now));
            } else {
                TimeZone javaTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.convertToJavaTimeZone(tz, now);
                views.setViewVisibility(TIME_IDS[n], View.VISIBLE);
                RemoteViewUtil.setTextClockTimeZone(views, TIME_IDS[n], javaTimeZone.getID());
            }
            n++;
        }
        int showEmptyText = (n == 0) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.empty_text, showEmptyText);
        for (; n < CITY_IDS.length; n++) {
            views.setTextViewText(CITY_IDS[n], "");
            if (SANS_JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                views.setTextViewText(TIME_IDS[n], "");
            } else {
                views.setViewVisibility(TIME_IDS[n], View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        boolean customColors = prefs.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.use_custom_colors_key), false);
        int textColor = Color.WHITE;
        if (customColors) {
            int color = prefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.background_color_key), Color.BLACK);
            RemoteViewUtil.setBackgroundColor(views, R.id.app_widget, color);
            textColor = prefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.foreground_color_key), Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            RemoteViewUtil.setBackground(views, R.id.app_widget, R.drawable.appwidget_dark_bg);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CITY_IDS.length; i++) {
            views.setTextColor(CITY_IDS[i], textColor);
            views.setTextColor(TIME_IDS[i], textColor);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onClockTick(Context context) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, WorldClockWidgetService.class);
    context.startService(service);
}

static void updateTime(Context context) {
    // update on the hour
    final long minutes = System.currentTimeMillis() / (60000);
    if (minutes % 60 == 0) {
        Clocks.updateOrder(context);
    }
    // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then call the shared
    // clock update method.
    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), WorldClockWidgetProvider.class.getName());
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
    for (int appWidgetID: ids) {
        updateAppWidgetStatic(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: maybe this is related to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all (from an answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452301/java-lang-illegalstateexception-at-android-app-contextimpl-startservicecommon) -- From which api version did you migrate from?

Comment: @second I was upgrading from targetSdkVersion 22 to 28. updated the build.gradle.snippit is updated.

Comment: Can you confirm that the service you are trying to run is indeed a background service?

Comment: @second I think it is calling intent service. Updated code.

Comment: Yes it's a background services

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the following links:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) also includes the following changes to
>   specific methods:
>
> The `startService()` method now throws an `IllegalStateException` if an
>   app targeting Android 8.0 tries to use that method in a situation when
>   it isn't permitted to create background services.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

> **Note:** `IntentService` is a service, and is therefore subject to the new
>   restrictions on background services. As a result, many apps that rely
>   on IntentService do not work properly when targeting Android 8.0 or
>   higher. For this reason, Android Support Library 26.0.0 introduces a
>   new `JobIntentService` class, which provides the same functionality as
>   IntentService but uses jobs instead of services when running on
>   Android 8.0 or higher.

So you need to take a look at the JobIntentService & JobScheduler classes and replace you old background service code with that.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService for an example of such a job.

Comment: Thanks for your Solution it is well written. I have updated the question with **proposed solution** I am getting error which is updated after changing to **JobIntent** service

Comment: The `JobIntentService` class only has a default constructor, so removing the whole constructor or just writing super() instead would solve your issues. Do you need the old service name for anything?

Comment: Thanks @second. after removing it worked. but the widget is failing now. I have updated the * WorldClockWidgetProvider* code. let me knw if any more code required.

Comment: Consider asking a new question for these problems. Add any stacktrace or error that you are facing now as well. And you probably need to change the `onClickTime` method to a job.

Comment: Thanks.Do you mean This method ?`@Override
protected void onClockTick(Context context) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, WorldClockWidgetService.class);
    context.startService(service);
}`